# How to send an specific sheet in pdf in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’ve been trying to find a way to send via email in pdf, an specific sheet I have in a google drive. It’s a receipt I want to send to customers but when the pdf is generated sometimes it sends the whole document and now I’m stuck with the error “TypeError: sourceSheet.getBlob is not a function myFunction @ Code.gs:29

The code I have is the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Recibo");

  // Check if "Control" sheet exists
  var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Control");
  if (!targetSheet) {
    targetSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet("Control");
    // Adjust any desired settings or formatting for the "Control" sheet here
  }

  // Create a temporary copy of the source sheet
  var tempSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(spreadsheet);
  tempSheet.setName("TempSheet");

  // Delete unwanted sheets from the temporary copy
  var sheets = tempSheet.getParent().getSheets();
  for (var i = sheets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (sheet.getName() !== "Control" && sheet.getName() !== "Recibo") {
      // Check if sheet exists before trying to delete it
      if (spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet.getName())) {
        spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
      }
    }
  }

  // Generate a PDF version of the temporary sheet
  var pdfBlob = sourceSheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

  // Get the recipient email address from a specific cell
  var recipientEmailRange = sourceSheet.getRange("C16");
  var recipientEmail = recipientEmailRange.getValue();

  // Send the email with the PDF attachment
  var subject = "Recibo de gastos legales";
  var body = "Estimado cliente, adjunto encontrará su recibo de gastos legales.";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, body, { attachments: [pdfBlob] });

  // Copy specific cells to the "Control" sheet
  var targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow, 1).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange("L8").getValue());
  targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow, 2).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange("L10").getValue());
  targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow, 3).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange("C14").getValue());
  targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow, 4).setValue(sourceSheet.getRange("L18").getValue());

  // Delete the temporary sheet
  spreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
}
```

I have tried to work on separate documents but haven’t made it work and I’m stuck right now

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line of code.

```html
var pdfBlob = spreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed the code and there’s an error - ReferenceError: spreadSheet is not defined

Comment: @DavidPalma are you running this code on the script editor or by trigger or how?

Comment: Hello Mauricio, I’m running it in the script editor. Haven’t tried to run it by triggering it yet.

Comment: @DavidPalma probably the `sourceSheet` is undefined. Check first if the `sourceSheet` variable has data. I do recall reading in another question here on Stack Overflow about this issue. It might be the spreadsheet must be opened by id - if it's by editor - or by name o active spreadsheet, so, try these options and let us know.

Comment: Hello, I’ve managed to make the code work partially, it now sends the pdf via email, but it still keeps sending the whole document (two sheets). I’ve double checked the variables, but I’ll go through them again

Comment: @DavidPalma mayeb is because you're sending the spreadsheet, not sheet. So, try: `sourceSheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');` - or `targetSheet` - it's not clear to me which sheet you want to send as PDF...

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that code. I’m trying to send a sheet called “Recibo”